# The data source does not support server-side data paging. .toList() is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ado.net

I'm trying to load some data from a database, and to filter them using this method.
Now, i want also to show them by pages, especially at the non-filtered part.

I used a `DataAdaptor` to fill up a dataset table, on which I'm making my filtering.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(CS);
        string query = "select * from table1";
        OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(query, con);

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "mytbl");
        Session["DATASET"] = dataSet;

        GridView1.DataSource = from dataRow in dataSet.Tables["mytbl"].AsEnumerable()
                               orderby dataRow["ID"]
                               select new guards
                               {
                                   ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow["ID"]),
                                   Nume = dataRow["NUME"].ToString()
                               };
        GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: You're filling a `DataSet`, but your not using a `DataSet`. You're using a collection of "guard" returned from a linq statement. If the collection does not support paging, which means at minimum it must support `ICollection`, then you cannot page. I don't know enough about linq to know what's it's returning, but I do know you cannot page a `GridView` just by enabling the paging property.  Maybe fill a Collection that implements ICollection and set the gridview datasource to that.  or...it may just need to be cast to an appropriate collection

Comment: do you get any data returned when you use the QuickWatch hovering over `dataSet..? if not then change your `dataAdatpter.Fill` method to the following 
`dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);` also wrap the Oracle Data Objects and Oracle Connection object around a `using(){}` also I think that you should set the end of the Linq statement to use `.ToList()` when binding why not just set the datasource to the dataSet..

Comment: grammar/formatting/spelling fixed

Comment: Hello guys!
I'm still confused!
everything works perfectly .. i can even filter the data, using a `where (dataRow["Nume"].ToString().Contains("George")` clause  ... but i cannot use the paging function.
I've used this function before with DataGrid and it worked! Though, never combined with filters.

Is there any other way to do the filters then? How to filter my GridView or my dataset .. or the table inside?
I need to put in my form filters by columns! Though, there's a lot of info and i kinda need paging also .. 

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You will have to tell ASP.NET how to page. in this case it is .Skip().Take()